# SQL SELECT statement for 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, select

In my webservice I need to be able to pull from 3 different tables to get my search to work. I have an autocompleteextender control on one page that searches by a description, but instead of displaying the description, it should display all of the products that have the word or phrase entered.

Ex: I enter the word "here" and the autocompleteextender will show products that have the word "here" in their description.

The description of the product is in one table that gets linked to the product table by a table that holds ids for both the product and the description. Therefore, I need 3 tables to be linked. I've always had troubles when it came to joining multiple tables together, I was hoping someone could help?

Here is my statement:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT p.ProductID,
                p.ProductName
FROM   Product p
       INNER JOIN Marketing m
         ON p.ProductID = m.ProductID
       JOIN Feature f
         ON f.FeatureID = m.MarketingData
WHERE  f.FeatureTitle LIKE '%" & prefixText & "%'
ORDER  BY p.ProductName ASC"
```

It pulls a null value when I type it into SQL Server so obviously something is wrong here. [image: Database Structure]

Comment: The query looks ok. Just make sure you have corresponding data. You could try a search without the where condition to check if your JOIN yields any results.

Comment: Are you sure that you have a `featuretitle` that contains the word you are searching?

Comment: I've tried using the statement using '%a' when searching for a featuretitle but I will try what @MicSim has suggested now. Didn't even think of that

Comment: A shot in the dark: looks like `prefixText` is a variable in VB (or VB.Net or Asp) and you are concatenating in the software. If you run the EXACT query you posted here, it will definitely not work.

Comment: I took the where out and sql server told me it couldn't convert MarketingData into an int, that's when I realized that I wasn't telling it that MarketingData needs to = 3. 3 is telling the database that MarketingData is a feature. 3 links MarketingData to the Feature table, where Feature holds all the Descriptions. Thanks for telling me to try without the where or I might've been stuck all day! It works great now!

Comment: @jlg what does link Tables(CategoryLink,TargetLink,....) do??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want only the rows on products that have the given text on his matching featuretitle of the feature table you need to use INNER JOIN in order to supress all non necessary rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    p.productid,
    p.productname
FROM product p
INNER JOIN marketing m ON p.productid = m.productid
INNER JOIN feature f ON f.featureid = m.marketingdata
WHERE  f.featuretitle LIKE '%@TextYouSearchFor%'
ORDER  BY p.productname ASC
```

With this sentence you will only get the rows in products that have a matching description on feature table.

**Added for clarification purposes:**

If possible use a parametrized query passing the searched text as a parameter. This will avoid some possible errors with texts containing reserved SQL characters like ' or ,

Specify allways the kind of join you want, like INNER JOIN, etc...

Comment: This is the same query posted by OP

Comment: Yes, with some minor changes:
1.- The use of parameters that will avoid failures if the searched text contains ' or ,
2.- The specification of INNER JOIN in both joins eliminating some ambiguity

A great number of errors come from these two little things people tend to forget

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want (distinct) results from the `product` table, you could drop the `DINSTINCT` and use `GROUP BY p.productid` or rewrite the query with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT p.productid,
       p.productname
FROM   product p
WHERE  EXISTS
         ( SELECT *
           FROM   marketing m
             JOIN feature f
               ON f.featureid = m.marketingdata
           WHERE  m.productid = p.productid
             AND  m.MarketingTypeID = 3 
             AND  f.featuretitle LIKE '%" & prefixText & "%'
         )
ORDER  BY
       p.productname ASC
```

The performance killer in this query may be the `LIKE '%Text%'` though. If you try it with `LIKE 'Text%'` and is much faster, that's the reason of slowness.

Comment: Wouldn't I need to have a % before and after the Text though? That way it searches before and after the word?

Comment: Yes, I meant to test without the `%` at the beginning as a speed test only.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the SELECT statement to this thanks to @MicSim and @Doliveras for suggesting a different statement to test for errors.

```
"Select DISTINCT 
p.ProductID, p.ProductName 
FROM Product p 
INNER JOIN Marketing m ON p.ProductID = m.ProductID 
INNER JOIN Feature f ON f.FeatureID =  m.MarketingData 
WHERE m.MarketingTypeID = 3 
AND f.FeatureTitle 
LIKE '%@prefixText%' 
ORDER BY p.ProductName ASC"
```

Answer (score -1):

If one of your tables may not have any data for a particular key (ProductID, FeatureID etc) then you should use an outer join, to ensure you still get data back for the joined table.

Comment: -1 OP is searching products by feature, so that does not apply since if there's no data for the feature (or marketing), the product should not come in the result.